# what case Kruskal's not getting minimum?

Tags: algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

Since the Kruskal algorithm is greedy approach, that means we may not getting real minimum path sometime.

But could anyone give a case that shows this algorithm's not getting the minimum?

I am not looking for complexity, just need a case that really not getting optimal solution.

Thanks

Comment: Not all greedy algorithms are sub-optimal.  Kruskal's always finds a minimum spanning tree.

Comment: There seems to be some misunderstanding. First, there seems to be the impression that a greedy algorithm as such is always unable to solve each of its instances to optimality; this is not true. Second, there seems to be the assumption that Kruskal's algorithm (which calculates a minimum spanning tree) calculates a path; please clarify on that. However, note that a minimum spanning tree is in general not a tree of shortest paths for between any two vertices - is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I think Kruskal's algorithm will always find the optimal solution. It even works with the graph with negative edge cost.
There is a proof about the optimality of Kruskal's greedy algorithm from textbook named as *Algorithm Design*:
Consider any edge e = (v, w) added by Kruskal’s Algorithm, and let S be the set of all nodes to which v has a path at the moment just before e is added. Clearly v ∈ S, but w ̸∈ S, since adding e does not create a cycle. Moreover, no edge from S to V − S has been encountered yet, since any such edge could have been added without creating a cycle, and hence would have been added by Kruskal’s Algorithm. Thus e is the cheapest edge with one end in S and the other in V − S, so it belongs to every minimum spanning tree.
So if we can show that the output (V , T ) of Kruskal’s Algorithm is in fact a spanning tree of G, then we will be done. Clearly (V, T) contains no cycles, since the algorithm is explicitly designed to avoid creating cycles. Further, if (V , T ) were not connected, then there would exist a nonempty subset of nodes S (not equal to all of V) such that there is no edge from S to V −S. But this contradicts the behavior of the algorithm: we know that since G is connected, there is at least one edge between S and V − S, and the algorithm will add the first of these that it encounters.

Comment: The OP asked about *not* getting the optimal solution.